# Закрыть div по клику вне его пределов

Tags: javascript, html

Привет. Есть функция по клику которой показывается и скрывается дополнительное меню на сайте:

```html
 var nav = {
  // Доп. меню шапка сайта
  showTM: function() {
    var openMenu = document.getElementById("openTM");
    var contentMenu = document.getElementById("dopMenuTop");
    if(openMenu){
      contentMenu.innerHTML = '<div class="absolute dop_menu_top" ><span id="sdfsdf"></span><nav><ul><li><a href="">' + js3 + '</a></li><li><a href="">' + js4 + '</a></li><li><a href="">' + js5 + '</a></li><li><a href="">' + js6 + '</a></li><li class="li"><div></div></li><li><a href="">' + js7 + '</a></li><li><a href="">' + js8 + '</a></li><li><a href="">' + js9 + '</a></li></ul></nav></div>';
      openMenu.classList.add("active");
   openMenu.onclick = nav.clouseTM; 
    }
  }, 
  clouseTM: function() {
    var openMenu = document.getElementById("openTM");
    var contentMenu = document.getElementById("dopMenuTop");
    if(openMenu){
      contentMenu.innerHTML = '';
      openMenu.classList.remove("active");
      openMenu.onclick = nav.showTM;
    }  
  }
```

```
<li class="relative"><a id="openTM" class="lio" onClick="nav.showTM(); return false;"></a>
    <div id="dopMenuTop"></div>
    </li>
```

Вопрос как мне скрыть блок по клику за его пределами, например если пользователь кликнул по новой ссылке или в пустое поле?

Comment: Вы используете Jquery  в вашем проекте?

Comment: нет только javascript

Answer (score 0):

может что-то такое подойдет

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
  var div = $("#id"); // тут указываем ID элемента
  if (!div.is(e.target)// если клик был не по нашему блоку
    && div.has(e.target).length === 0){// и не по его дочерним элементам
      чето делаем
  }
});
```