# Как закрыть боковое меню кликнув вне его?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется вот такой код бокового меню. Как сделать чтобы при открытии и при клике в любом месте экрана оно закрывалось. В данном коде стоит крестик но я его спрятал, так как для дизайна он не подходит и пришлось его спрятать от пользователя.

```css
.hidden-menu{display:block;position:fixed;list-style:none;padding:15px 5px;margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;width:250px;height:100%;top:0;left:-250px;background-color:#060606;z-index:999}
.hidden-menu li{padding:10px 0}
.hidden-menu a{font-weight:700;color:#fff;letter-spacing:2px;text-decoration:none}
.hidden-menu-ticker{display:none}
.btn-menu{border:2px solid #F99806;border-radius:5px;color:#fff;padding:5px;position:fixed;top:30px;left:15px;cursor:pointer;z-index:0;width:40px}
.btn-menu span{display:block;height:6px;background-color:#f99806;margin:5px 0 0;position:relative}
.btn-menu span.first{margin-top:0}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu{left:195px}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .hidden-menu{left:0}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.second{opacity:0}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.first{width:20px}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.third{top:-22px;width:20px}
.hidden-menu li{border-bottom:1px dotted #ddd;padding:15px;cursor:pointer}
.hidden-menu li > a{display:block}
.hidden-menu li:hover{background:rgba(221,221,221,0.54);border-bottom:0}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">
<label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
 <span class="first"></span>
 <span class="second"></span>
 <span class="third"></span>
</label>
<ul class="hidden-menu">
<li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: в блоке справа есть полно связанных и похожих вопросов... вы смотрели туда? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/140922 | https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/504193 | https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433249

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте ещё один label, который появляется только после выделения checkbox и растягивается на всю страницу

```css
.hidden-menu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -250px;
  background-color: #060606;
  z-index: 999
}

.hidden-menu li {
  padding: 10px 0
}

.hidden-menu a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none
}

.hidden-menu-ticker {
  display: none
}

.btn-menu {
  border: 2px solid #F99806;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 40px
}

.btn-menu span {
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #f99806;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: relative
}

.btn-menu span.first {
  margin-top: 0
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.btn-menu {
  left: 195px
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.hidden-menu {
  left: 0
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.btn-menu span.second {
  opacity: 0
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.btn-menu span.first {
  width: 20px
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.btn-menu span.third {
  top: -22px;
  width: 20px
}

.hidden-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.hidden-menu li>a {
  display: block
}

.hidden-menu li:hover {
  background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.54);
  border-bottom: 0
}

.hide-after-open {
  display: none;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.hide-after-open {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">
<label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
 <span class="first"></span>
 <span class="second"></span>
 <span class="third"></span>
</label>
<label class="hide-after-open" for="hmt"></label>
<ul class="hidden-menu">
  <li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="">ссылка</a></li>
</ul>
```